# Heroku run process using JRuby 1.7 and Rails 3.2 hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, jruby

I was able to get the web process on heroku running with JRuby and trinidad.  I am using this in my Gemfile, which seems to be the best practice over a custom heroku buildpack at this point:

```
ruby "1.9.3", :engine => "jruby", :engine_version => "1.7.0"
```

However, in trying to load the database (or connect to the rails console) via:

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load
```

or

```
heroku run console
```

The command just hangs.  Tailing the heroku logs I see the process starting up and completing without error, but I never get any output back on the local command line and it just hangs.

```
2012-11-16T16:02:46+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:schema:load`
2012-11-16T16:02:51+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
2012-11-16T16:02:51+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:schema:load`
2012-11-16T16:02:51+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-11-16T16:02:51+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-11-16T16:03:21+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-11-16T16:03:21+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
2012-11-16T16:03:21+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

I'm guessing I need to do add a rake and console item in the Procfile and tried some various combinations but nothing was working.  It always hangs.  I also didn't see anyone else's Procfile for JRuby including these items.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue with running the heroku gem from within JRuby.  Running the commands via heroku toolbelt from outside of JRuby (MRI 1.9.3) works fine.